# Problem with passing parameter through URL to an LWC present inside a lightning tab

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, detail-page, lightning-tab

I have a detail page button on Account Detail page. I wish to open an LWC on clicking the button. The button opens a lightning tab using URL and passes a parameter along with the URL. I have an LWC on the lightning tab with utilizes that URL parameter.

**Problem:** The lightning tab does not get the parameter in the URL. Hence LWC does not get the parameter.

**Lightning tab name:** `Cops_Rate_Profile_Tab`

**Detail page button URL:** `/lightning/n/Cops_Rate_Profile_Tab?MDMID={!Account.Master_Customer_ID__c}`

**LWC gets the URL parameter as follows:**

```js
export default class CopsRateProfileLWC extends LightningElement {

    MDMID; 

    connectedCallback() {

        //Get the MDMID from the URL
        this.MDMID = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('MDMID');

    }
}
```

I referred [this](https://sfcure.com/2017/10/11/are-you-looking-for-a-way-to-open-a-lightning-component-in-a-new-tabwindow-on-detail-page-button-click/) website.

I am not able to find what is going wrong. Please guide. Thank You!

Comment: Is this on Lightning Console Tab ?

Comment: @NagendraSingh No. It's not on console tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a namespace prefix for your query parameter. If the component isn’t part of a managed package you should use `c__` as prefix.
So the button url would be `/lightning/n/Cops_Rate_Profile_Tab?c__MDMID={!Account.Master_Customer_ID__c}` and in the controller you should get `c__MDMID`.
Please refer to the documentation about [query parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_navigate_add_params_url).